WebRTC: Consumer Transport Created Successfully but Client Disconnects Immediately in mediasoup
I'm working on a WebRTC application using mediasoup for screen sharing. The Producer side works fine, but I'm having issues with the Consumer side. The Consumer Transport is created successfully, but the client disconnects immediately after receiving the transport parameters.
Here's the flow of what's happening:

The server creates the Consumer Transport and sends the parameters to the client.
The client receives the parameters.
Immediately after this, the client disconnects.

I've verified that the Producer is working correctly and can send data. The issue seems to be specific to the Consumer setup.
Here's the relevant client-side code for creating the Consumer Transport:
const handleNewScreenShare = async ({
  memberId,
  producerId,
  resolution,
  frameRate,
}: ScreenShareParams) => {
  if (memberId === Profile.memberId) {
    return;
  }
  console.log('handleNewScreenShare==============:');
  console.log('memberId:', memberId);
  console.log('producerId:', producerId);
  console.log('resolution:', resolution);
  console.log('frameRate:', frameRate);

  if (!socketRef.current) {
    console.error('handleNewScreenShare ========> Socket is null');
    return;
  }

  socketRef.current.emit(
    'createConsumerTransport',
    { consumer: true },
    (params: any) => {
      console.log('createConsumerTransport params:', params);
      if (!device.current) {
        console.error('Device is null');
        return;
      }
      consumerTransport.current = device.current.createRecvTransport(params);
      console.log('consumerTransport==========:', consumerTransport);

      consumerTransport.current.on(
        'connect',
        async (
          { dtlsParameters }: any,
          callback: FuncType,
          errback: FuncType,
        ) => {
          console.log(
            'consumerTransport connect 호출 dtlsParameters:',
            dtlsParameters,
          );
          try {
            socketRef.current?.emit(
              'connectConsumerTransport',
              {
                dtlsParameters,
              },
              (response: any) => {
                console.log('Response from server:', response);
              },
            );
            callback();
          } catch (err) {
            console.error('Failed to connect consumer transport:', err);
          }
        },
      );

      // ... rest of the code
    },
  );
};

And here's the server-side log showing the transport creation and immediate disconnection:
WebRTC Transport created successfully: {
  id: '6dd2112231230640b',
  iceParameters: {
    usernameFragment: 'x615d46ds213412421421wdqdddrwuoi1q',
    password: 'n21212e8wqdqwdwqd1213b5ycesv8',
    iceLite: true
  },
  iceCandidates: [
    {
      foundation: 'udpcandidate',
      priority: 1376302079,
      ip: '3.33.393.333',
      address: '3.34.333.132',
      protocol: 'udp',
      port: 10005,
      type: 'host',
      tcpType: undefined
    },
    {
      foundation: 'tcpcandidate',
      priority: 1076276479,
      ip: '3.34.193.132',
      address: '3.34.193.132',
      protocol: 'tcp',
      port: 10013,
      type: 'host',
      tcpType: 'passive'
    }
  ],
  dtlsParameters: {
    fingerprints: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    role: 'auto'
  }
}
Max incoming bitrate set to 1500000
Returning transport parameters: {
  // ... same as above ...
}
callback 완료!!!!
Client disconnected: 3 from room 111
User 3 left study room 111
Attempting to remove member 3 from room 111
Member 3 removed from room 111
Broadcasting room update for room 111: [ { memberId: '56', appInfo: 'Steam' } ]

I've already tried the following:

Checking for any errors in the client console (none reported)
Verifying that the ICE candidates are correctly received
Ensuring that the DTLS parameters are properly set

What could be causing the client to disconnect immediately after receiving the Consumer Transport parameters? How can I debug this further or resolve the issue?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Tags
webrtc, mediasoup, typescript, screen-sharing## Tags
webrtc, mediasoup, typescript, screen-sharing
